# Is there a Haskell equivalent of F# units of measure?

Tags: haskell, f#

F# has a units of measure capability, described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx as follows:

```ml
[<Measure>] type unit-name [ = measure ]
```

This allows units to be defined such as:

```ml
type [<Measure>] USD
type [<Measure>] EUR
```

And code to be written as:

```ml
let dollars = 25.0<USD>
let euros   = 25.0<EUR>

// Results in an error as the units differ
if dollars > euros then printfn "Greater!"
```

It also handles conversions (I'm guessing that means Measure has some functions defined that let Measures be multiplied, divided and exponentiated):

```ml
// Mass, grams.
[<Measure>] type g
// Mass, kilograms.
[<Measure>] type kg

let gramsPerKilogram: float<g kg^-1> = 1000.0<g/kg>

let convertGramsToKilograms (x: float<g>) = x / gramsPerKilogram
```

My instincts tell me it should be possible to implement a similar capability in Haskell, but I've not been able to find any examples of how to do it.

Edit: oh my word it's a huge can of worms! There's a research paper at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/akenn/units/CEFP09TypesForUnitsOfMeasure.pdf. I'm guessing it's more than a few lines of code to implement the whole thing. Summer project anyone? :)

Comment: I'd think you would have to make your own type class for currency then write your own instances for Ord and Eq to do the conversion based comparison.  Same could be done for lengths, masses, etc.

Comment: Have a look at [dimensional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional). The Hackage documentation is non-existent, but there are some examples [on the wiki](https://code.google.com/p/dimensional/w/list?q=label:Example).

Comment: `dimensional` is a good suggestion for actual physical units, but not for money.

Comment: The RWH book has [a chapter](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/data-structures.html) where they show you how to start rolling your own. (search for "unit")

Answer (score 12):

Wrap numbers in a newtype and give them a `Num` instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype GBP n = GBP n deriving (Show, Num, Eq, Ord)
newtype USD n = USD n deriving (Show, Num, Eq, Ord)
```

Usage:

```
ghci> let a1 = GBP 2
ghci> let a2 = GBP 5
ghci> a1 + a2
GBP 7
ghci> let b1 = USD 3
ghci> let b2 = USD 6
ghci> b1 + b2
USD 9
ghci> a1 + b2 -- should be an error for mixing currencies

<interactive>:8:6:
    Couldn't match expected type `GBP Integer'
                with actual type `USD Integer'
    In the second argument of `(+)', namely `b2'
    In the expression: a1 + b2
    In an equation for `it': it = a1 + b2
```

Comment: I don't know much Haskell, but one of the powers of F# units is that they support multiplication - eg `1<m> / 1<s> = 1<m/s>` which means you can get support for type checking of physical equations.  Does your Haskell implement this?

Comment: @JohnPalmer As I've written it, no that wouldn't work. It would require a slightly more complicated system to accomplish that. The [dimensional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional) package mentioned by leftaroundabout covers that sort of thing, but I don't know how generically, as I haven't used it yet.

Comment: @JohnPalmer your example certainly prevents accidental treatment of one type as the other one which is about as powerful as Java and C# can manage! I'd love to know if it's possible to achieve in Haskell the full capability of the F# example (or indeed to find out if they've cheated in some way and bodged it into the language).

Comment: Problem of deriving is `Num` is it allows multiplication wich is wrong (as multiplying units should change the dimension)

Answer (score 7):

The [dimensional](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional) and [dimensional-tf](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dimensional-tf) (with type families instead of multi-parameter type classes) libraries are pretty nice and can handle most of the issues presented in your example.

I don't think the library lets you define custom dimensions like currencies, though. As far as I know you would need to modify the library code to do that.

Answer (score 4):

OK. I know the question is too old. But, there is a GHC plugin build to provide unit of measure capability in Haskell. Please refer to this Adam Gundry's [paper](http://adam.gundry.co.uk/pub/typechecker-plugins/typechecker-plugins-2015-03-03.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The [units](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/units) package seems promising and allows conversion between different unit of the same dimension. However, I haven't used it and I don't know if it's stable or not. In fairness, I tried to install it today and the installation failed ...

Answer (score 1):

Check haskell.org wikipage about enforcing units in Haskell first:

https://wiki.haskell.org/Physical_units

There are multiple options but I'm not sure if there actually is something similar to "Units of Measure" you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Haskell much though I am interested in learning and am still junior with F#, however, it seems a general solution should be around treating measures as a tuple of scalar and a label representing the unit, (N,M).

For example, let measure be a generic tuple of `measure<N,M>`, where `N` is a number and `M` is a `string`, then `=, +, -, *, /, ^` can be overloaded to implement evaluation for given measures, `a, b, and c`, scalar `p`, boolean k, and measure label normalizing function `norm` such that

```
a = b = (Na,Ma) = (Nb,Mb) = (Na = Nb) and norm(Ma) = norm(Mb) = k
a + b = (Na,Ma) + (Nb,Mb) = (Na + Nb, Ma) = c provided norm(Ma) = norm(Mb)
a * b = (Na,Ma) * (Nb,Mb) = (Na * Nb, Ma * Mb) = c
a ^ p = (Na,Ma) ^ p       = (Na ^ p , Ma ^ p ) = c
....
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the problem, which is about using the type system to verify, statically, that calculations involving units are sane.